# Grouping objects in a focus/blur event

Tags: jquery

I saw an example to use `.is(":focus")` to check if another object is in focus, but it's not working as expected.  I'm using FireFox, and expect it to work in all browsers supporting jQuery.

Html:

```
 <input class=a value=a>
 <input class=b value=b>

 ^ focus on the input a
 How to make input.b stay visible when focus moves off .a and to .b?
```

Js:

```
 $(".a").focus(function(){
     $(".b").show();   
 });

 $(".a,.b").blur(function(){
     var f = false;
     if($(".a").is(":focus")) var f = true;
     if($(".b").is(":focus")) var f = true;
     if(!f) $(".b").hide();
 });
```

Input.b always hides when i move focus to it, but it shouldn't.

Here's a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/7gXfC/1/

I don't see how else to do this

Comment: When are you supposed to hide b?

Comment: @j809 Well when `.a` and `.b` are both blurred at the same time.

Comment: How can .a and .b blur same time?? Double keyboard?? :) Do you mean "when .a and .b don't have a focus"?

Comment: @Hardy ok I should say when both `.a` and `.b` have lost focus. Please see the 2nd event in the above code.

Comment: Why you need something like this? What your are trying to do with it in "real world"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a work around, but you can try this:

```
$(".a").focus(function(){
    $(".b").show();   
});

/*
   Added a timeout so b.focus event occurs before a.blur
*/
$(".a").blur(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(!$(".b").is(":focus")) $(".b").hide();
    }, 50);
});

$(".b").focus(function(){
    $(".b").show();
});

$(".b").blur(function(){
    $(".b").hide();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7gXfC/6/)

Comment: Negative. I'm using FF 30 and it's not working either.

Comment: Seems like the timeout fixes it in FF. Looks good. Thanks. And yes, it does work in chrome. Not sure about IE however.

Comment: @ZeeTee [I posted a question on this odd behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24635536/1492578). Didn't get an answer yet, though.