# Primefaces - Internet Explorer - Must click 2 times for converterMessage to show

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces

I have an inputText field like this:

```
<p:inputText value="#{backend.longAttribute}" converterMessage="Must be a number">
  <p:ajax event="blur" update="something" />
</p:inputText>
```

The inputText goes to an attribute of type Long.
When I write something there, and click a button, then the message "Must be a number" is gonna show.
In Chrome everything is fine. I write "abc", and the message shows up.
In Internet explorer, I have to first click it one time, then another time for the message to show.

Any idea? Im using PrimeFaces 5.8 or something. Its not 6.

Edit:

So my problem was this: `<p:ajax event="blur" update="something" />`
When I write something in the inputText field, and click my commandButton without clicking or doing anything else, then then only the blur will activate. If I click out of the inputText field first, so the blur will finish first, then I only need to click the button once. Anyone have any idea for how to let commandButtons action be called right after blur, without clicking twise?

Example for when I need it:

I have an input field. The data in the field should have this format: `1:00`. When a user write the number `1` then the ajax event will add the `:00`. But I also want the user to be able to write `1`, and the click a button without first having to take focus away from the inputfield first.

Comment: ?????_Any idea? Im using PrimeFaces 5.8 or something. Its not 6._ Seriously... You don't know the version you are using or whether it exists at all??? And IE6 is not supported!an

Comment: does it work with a plain jsf inputText and ajax tag?

Comment: I changed <p:inputText> to <h:inputText>, and use <p:ajax>, but the problem is still there. I have to click 2 times for the errormessage to show. And it is still only on internet explorer

Comment: So it is effectively not a PrimeFaces but already/also a plain jsf one...  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635536/different-behavior-of-blur-event-in-different-browsers and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769005/onclick-and-onblur-ordering-issue/28963938#28963938